# A simple foldRight type issue in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm doing a simple exercise in building my own List. I want to define a method that converts a regular list to `MyList`.  The recursive version seems fine, but when I try to convert that to a `foldRight` I get a diagnostic referring to `MyNonEmpty[T](x, ys)` that says:

```
- type mismatch; found : MyNonEmpty[T] required: MyEmpty[T]
```

I'd appreciate help in understanding this.

```
abstract class MyList[T] {

  def listToMyList1(xs: List[T]): MyList[T] = xs match {
    case Nil => MyEmpty[T]
    case y :: ys => MyNonEmpty[T](y, listToMyList1(ys))
  }

  def listToMyList2(xs: List[T]): MyList[T] =
    xs.foldRight(MyEmpty[T])((x: T, ys: MyList[T]) => MyNonEmpty[T](x, ys))


case class MyEmpty[T] extends MyList[T] 

case class MyNonEmpty[T](val head: T, val tail: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T]
```

Comment: I think you should put your listToMyList functions in the MyList companion object. It is awkward to have them defined in an abstract class since they don't use `this` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick solution to the problem is, explicitly define the expected type of `B`.

```
val empty:MyList[T] = MyEmpty[T]
xs.foldRight(empty)((x, ys) => MyNonEmpty[T](x, ys))
```

If you are going in depth of the problem, it can be described as follows.

The signature of `foldRight` is as follows.

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Here `type B` is defined as a method type parameter. And in Scala, you cannot define type variance in the type parameters defined in methods.

```
def func[+A](a:A) = ... //Compiler error
```

And as the second point, if you have multiple parameter lists, It behaves almost as curried functions.

```
def func(a:Int)(b:Int) = ... // is almost equal to 
def func(a:Int) = (b:Int) => ...
```

So if you fill first arg list, it will create another function. In `foldRight` case, by filling `z` you define the type `B` too. If you didn't explicitly define the type of z. the concrete type is set as the `type B`. When you try to give a function `f` where returns a super type of B rather than `B`, the compiler fails.

This is a kind of problem in scala type inference, but there's no possible solution for this other than being explicit about the types.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.  It even works to do it like this. `xs.foldRight(MyEmpty[T]:MyList[T])((x, ys) => MyNonEmpty[T](x, ys))`   And I thought it would be some trivial thing that I hadn't noticed. This isn't quite so trivial. Glad to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the definition of `foldRight`:

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) ⇒ B): B
```

The type of z defines the return type, in your case `MyEmpty`. I see two options:

```
 sealed trait MyList[T]

 case class MyEmpty[T] extends MyList[T] 

 case class MyNonEmpty[T](val head: T, val tail: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T] 

 object MyList {

   def listToMyList1(xs: List[T]): MyList[T] =
    xs.foldRight[MyList[T]](MyEmpty[T])((x: T, ys: MyList[T]) => MyNonEmpty[T](x, ys))

   def listToMyList2(xs: List[T]): MyList[T] =
    xs.foldRight(MyEmpty[T].asInstanceOf[MyList[T]])((x: T, ys: MyList[T]) => MyNonEmpty[T](x, ys))
 }
```

As a side note: `MyEmpty` could be a singleton: `case object MyEmpty[Nothing]` with your sealed trait covariant: `sealed trait MyList[+T]. That way you only have one instance of an empty list that works with all values of your type parameter T.

Comment: Please, not `asInstanceOf`! Use plain type ascription!